# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=?;AT YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS MINUTE MINUTES, DRIVER=3.64.82

Tags: sql, groovy, db2

My code is looking like this:

```
addToTable2(ObjectDTO objectDTO) {
   def sql = sql.execute(
    """INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE2 (
        COLUMN1,
        COLUMN2,
        COLUMN3 )
        VALUES (
         ${objectDTO.property1}
         ${objectDTO.property2}
         ${objectDTO.property3})""")
}



ArrayList<ObjectDTO> fetchValuesFromTable1() throws CollectionsException {

    ArrayList<ObjectDTO> fetchValues= new ArrayList<ObjectDTO>()
    def sql = """
        SELECT *
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1
        ORDER BY DATE DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY"""

    try {
      if(this.sql != null) {
        this.sql.eachRow(sql) {
          resultSet ->
            ObjectDTO objectDTO = new ObjectDTO()
            objectDTO.setProperty1(resultSet.PROPERTY1)
            objectDTO.setProperty2(resultSet.PROPERTY2)
            objectDTO.setPropety3(resultSet.PROPERTY3)
      
             objectList.add(poulSifr)
           }
         }

      for(ObjectDTO objectDTO: objectList) {
        addToTable2(objectDTO)
      }

    } catch (SQLException se) {
      log.info "fetchValues error $se.message  executed sql: $sql"
       throw new CollectionsException("fetchValues message $se.message")
    } finally {
      if (this.sql != null) {
        this.sql.close()
      }
    }
    objectList
  }
```

I got this error/warning:

> WARN  groovy.sql.Sql - Failed to execute:  INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE (
> COLUMN1,
> COLUMN2,
> COLUMN3 )
> VALUES (
> ?,
> ?,
> null)
>
> because: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=?;AT
> YEAR YEARS MONTH MONTHS DAY DAYS HOUR HOURS MINUTE MINUTES,
> DRIVER=3.64.82

Whenever I fetch last value from Table1 I need to put that in Table2. I don't know is this proper way to do it or I'm doing something completely wrong.

Comment: show your table2 real definition - i guess you are using keywords as a table/column name.

Comment: can't show you real names of tables or columns. "SCHEMA" is schema name, "TABLE1" and "TABLE2" are names of tables.

Comment: What's the db2 platform and version? If it's Db2 for LUW, then please, provide some fully reproducible sample like [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=dfd150a176e7053dc598df668e5750e6), which works normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing commas in `VALUES(...)` part of insert